# Skyrim Mod: Equip a complete outfit

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

Is there a mod available, where I can have multiple items (like 2 weapons, armor and clothing) bound to one slot?

I'm actually trying to make outfits for different quests, because sometimes it's great to have the one abilities when the time I need the others.

TIA

Comment: Welcome to the site Silex! Your question was closed due to being a mod recommendation question. Recommendation questions can be problematic for Arqade since they don't always present a practical problem which can be solved, nor are the answers always going to be anything more than just users stating their opinions. Due to this, some recommendation question just don't work and are closed as "off-topic".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Categorized Favorites Menu](http://skyrim.nexusmods.com/mods/4862) provides this, although the last time I used it (a few versions back) it had a few quirks, and sometimes didn't actually equip everything it was meant to.  Might be fixed by now though.

Comment: SkyUI has group hotkey settings where you can add weapons armour- even multi slot armour pieces and ammo into one of its slots and are bound to a hotkey. And that just one of its minor features.
SkyUI needs SKSE